# Logstash failed to send join request to elasticsearch master

Tags: azure, logstash, elasticsearch

I have  a problem with my logstash that can't send log to elaticsearch.

With following details

1. Logstash version : 1.5.1
2. Elasticsearch version : 1.6.0
3. jvm on both servers version : 1.8.0
4. Linux 3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 23 22:06:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
5. Azure Openlogic 7.1

Here is my logstash.err file

```
INFO: [ls1] failed to send join request to master 
[[es1][e8A0li5pRfeMklozmDXgkQ][elastic][inet[/x.x.x.x:9300]]], reason  
[RemoteTransportException[[es1][inet[/x.x.x.x:9300]]
[internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested:  
ConnectTransportException[[ls1][inet[/x.x.x.x:9300]] 
connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: ConnectTimeoutException[connection 
timed out: /x.x.x.x:9300]; ]
```

My logstash configuration output

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host  => "x.x.x.x"
    bind_port => 9300
    index => "syslog"
    cluster => "test-cluster"
    node_name => 'ls1'
 }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

Here is my elasticsearch.yml configuration file in elasticsearch server

```
cluster.name: test-cluster
node.name: "es1"
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: <my_elasticsearch_public_ip>
transport.tcp.port: 9300
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["my_logstash_public_ip:9300"]
```

Here is my elasticsearch.yml file in logstash server (/var/lib/logstash)

```
network.publish_host: my_logstash_public_ip
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

I've allowed port 9300 on both servers.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I use Microsoft Azure VM, Now I can solve this problem by create VPN connection via azure virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include protocol attribute in your logstash configuration. find the below updated code.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    host  => "x.x.x.x"
    protocol => "http"
    bind_port => 9300
    index => "syslog"
    cluster => "test-cluster"
    node_name => 'ls1'
 }
```